# Django template tag variables are not working

Tags: html, django, templates, tags

{{ user }} shows users only in the index.html home page. In my other pages {{ user }} doesn't work.

I tried to put a simple "Test Text" and the text doesn't show up as well until I delete {% extends 'locator/base1.html' %}

Here is my base1.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>EME</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'locator/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'locator/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'locator/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'locator/css/creative.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body id="page-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav1">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'index' %}#page-top">Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'index' %}#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'index' %}#areas">Areas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'index' %}#locate">Church Locator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'index' %}#ministries">Ministries</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
              {% else %}
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my profile.html

```
{% extends 'locator/base1.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

{{ user.first_name }}
{{ user.last_name }}
{{ user.country }}
{{ user.city }}
{{ user.email }}


{% endblock %}
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account for {username} has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'locator/register.html', {'form': form })

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'locator/index.html', {})

def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'locator/profile.html', {})

def posts(request):
    return render(request, 'locator/posts.html', {})
```

And here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('posts/', views.posts, name='posts'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='locator/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='locator/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

Comment: The context for profile view is empty. How it can print user.ATTRIBUTE

Comment: from a database. Because user registered and put all the information to the database

Comment: @Almaz can you share your TEMPLATES setting?

Comment: Your base1.html seems to be incomplete. It does not have a closing body or html tag

Answer (score 1):

in your view you need to pass the context variables into the template like this:

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    # set variable in a dictionary
    context_dict = {'user': request.user}

    # pass dictionary to view with render 
    return render(request, 'locator/profile.html', context_dict)
```

You have access to any variables you pass in with the context_dict dictionary.

I hope this helps!